# Passing x,y coordinates of an image in LiveCode

Tags: screen, livecode

A screen shot of one of the cards in the LiveCode app that I'm working appears below.  The user is able to click on the icons and move them about the screen, ideally to rank order them using the boxes to the right.  In order to record the ranking of the icons, I'd like to get their y-coordinates -- that is, the higher the y-coordinate value, the lower the ranking.  I'm stumped on how pass the coordinates of the images to a variable, though.  I'm fairly new to LiveCode, so any help is much appreciated.[rating_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtULg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to LiveCode!

In LiveCode you have an attribute:

`the loc of image ”imagename”`

which you can pass as a variable to a procedure. That will contain both x **and** y of your image (or any control) separated by comma. To get just the y you need to get the second item of that. So you can either grab that in your procedure or directly when you pass it. Let’s say you have a procedure called `saveOrder` where you in some way save your data. The you can call that with the y-coordinate like:

```
saveOrder item 2 of the loc of image “imagename”
```

If you just want to grab something to determine which image is higher than the other you can instead use `the top` or `the bottom` instead of `item 2 of the loc`. Look them up in the dictionary for further explanations...

PS `the loc` is short for `the location` and of course you can write it out if you prefer it

Comment: @ hliljegren -- Thanks, works great!  By the way, also enjoying your post on OOP in LiveCode.

Answer (score 0):

Just an exercise: On a new card make two buttons. In the card script:

```
 on mouseMove
   if "button" is in the name of the target and the mouse is down then
     set the loc of the target to the mouseLoc
     put item 2 of the loc of the target
  end if
end mouseMove
```

Click on a button and drag it around. When you drag, the "Y" coordinate of the center of the button will appear in the message box. Of course, when you release, the last coordinate will stick.

As hliljegren points out, you may not want the center, but rather the top or some other point on the control of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You need just:

```
on MouseDown
   grab me
end MouseDown
```

Livecode is most simple and efficient language in the world!